# unable to get highcharts working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, highcharts

I'm trying to get Highcharts working in a Rails4 app.

I have included

```
gem 'highcharts-rails', '~> 3.0.0'
```

In my application.js file I have:

```
//= require highcharts
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more # to get the new features in 2.3.0
```

in my Gemfile, and have copied highcharts.js and highcharts-more.js to vendor/assets/javascripts. At the top of one of my .html.erb files I have put (copied and pasted from the highcharts documentation):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
});
```

When I view the page I get an error "wrong number of arguments (9 for 1)" on the line in my application.js file that says

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

I'm not sure where that line comes from, but if I comment out

```
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more # to get the new features in 2.3.0
```

from application.js the error goes away but the graph doesn't render, it just shows the javascript as text.

What am I missing?

I should add that I am a Rails novice and I know no javascript whatsoever.

Edit: Sample code for entire project is on [Dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/896430/demo.zip).

Edit2: Sample code corrected so the Javascript is in a  element. Now I don't see the Javascript, but I don't see anything else either.

Comment: Any other errors you can report? `"wrong number of arguments (9 for 1)"`is pretty ominous!

Comment: That's all I'm getting:

    Showing C:/Users/User/RubymineProjects/tf2/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:
    
    wrong number of arguments (9 for 1)
  (in C:/Users/User/RubymineProjects/tf2/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:18)

Comment: Do you have jQuery in your app?

Comment: Hmmm... Any chance you could post your rendered `application.js`? That call is on line 18, it will be helpful to see what it says

Comment: Oh, the label on the page is "Action Controller: Exception caught", and the page banner says "ArgumentError in Scenarios#new".

Comment: I have //= require jquery and //= require jquery_ujs in my application.js file.

How do I access the rendered application.js? (I'm using RubyMine if that makes it any easier).

Comment: Update the above application.js as in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that (most probably) you are using 2.x version, while constructor with jQuery was introduced in 3.x version. Change from:

```
$('#container').highcharts( options );
```

To:

```
new Highcharts.Chart( options );
```

Note: In second  constructor you need to add `chart.renderTo` to set container for Highcharts.

Comment: 2.x version of what? I'm using version 4.0.1 of Highcharts.

Comment: Of Highcharts. That line suggests something different: `//= require highcharts/highcharts-more # to get the new features in 2.3.0`

Comment: That line came from the example I was cutting and pasting.

Still, using `new Highcharts.Chart` does the trick, so this gets marked as the answer (although if that's an old-fashioned way of doing things I'm still interested in getting the up-to-date way working)

Comment: Try to update code from Highcharts CDN to make sure yu have 4.0.1 version, not 2.3.0.

Comment: I'm definitely using 4.0.1; that's what Highcharts.version returns in the Javascript console. Besides, I only downloaded Highcharts a few days ago!

Comment: Maybe jQuery is missing then?

Answer (score 1):

With gem added to the `Gemfile` and you have run the `bundle install` command.

Add this to your `application.js` file

```
//= require jquery-1.8.2.min
//= require jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min
//= require scripts 
//= require_directory.
```

`//= require scripts` // if you have javascripts or jQuery functions in script.js file

Add the `highcharts.js` under the `app/assets/javascripts` directory where all your `jQuery` are present.

Now just use the javascript include tag in your layout file as

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

now you are all set.

your html markup as it is

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
```

your script as it is

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
});
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: output image]

It worked for me.

Comment: That changes my error message to

"couldn't find file 'jquery-1.8.2.min'
  (in C:/Users/User/RubymineProjects/tf2/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:13)"

Comment: replace jquery-1.8.2.min with jquery.min.js in application.js file. Also remove //= require jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min if you dont have it under the javascript folder. If you have give the exact name.

Comment: That gives me the error "couldn't find file 'scripts'". If I take the //= require scripts line out of application.js then the page just shows the javascript listing (and a blank space where where I've put the `<div>` to reserve space).

Comment: Please update your question with exactly what you have in the app.

Comment: Even a bare Rails app is 15 kB, compressed, so I can't really include my app in my question! Which bits would be relevant?

Comment: But I've put a link to a zipped version on Dropbox -- based on the first example in Agile Web Development with Rails 4, the chart should appear in http://localhost:3000/say/hello but I get the Javascript code instead.